# I'm wondering if my 13 inch MacBook Air is having battery issues?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, battery

This is my current battery information. Could someone please let me know if I need a new battery or what might be wrong with it?

```
Battery Information:

Model Information:
  Serial Number:           D86221701NNDKRNA5
  Manufacturer:            SMP
  Device Name:               bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:           0
  PCB Lot Code:            0
  Firmware Version:        406
  Hardware Revision:       000a
  Cell Revision:           162

Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):  6098
  Fully Charged:           Yes
  Charging:                No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 6331

Health Information:
  Cycle Count:               60
  Condition:               Normal
  Battery Installed:       Yes
  Amperage (mA):           0
  Voltage (mV):            8293
```

Comment: If you add your Mac's model year (Mid 2010) or such, perhaps someone with one will post their FCC numbers for you to compare.

Comment: What makes you think you have battery issues in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics you print look decent for a lightly used, fully charged Air battery. Most of them have voltages between 8.1 and 8.4 V when fully charged.

I don't have recent full charge capacity numbers, but perhaps someone with an other similar Air will post their numbers. Since all batteries have slightly different charge and voltage behavior, you would need to monitor these numbers through several charge cycles (or see how your numbers are changing over time) to tell how the health of the battery is doing.

In reality, there probably are other things you can do to test your battery (like how long it takes to charge or how long it will run while awake and lightly loaded) and you will need to have a service technician run Apple's battery tests to tell if your snapshot numbers are within our out of spec.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using coconutBattery to monitor your battery life and record degradation statistics. For example, my MacbookPro is 21 months old, 142 cycles and has 94% of original capacity (6519 out of 6900). But Pro batteries are different from Airs, they degrade slower.

[Here](http://www.ifweassume.com/2013/08/the-de-evolution-of-my-laptop-battery.html) you can see how Air battery degrades over a year (recorded daily). Yours does not look different.